# cairo in gnome extension, nothing show

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I write simple test cairo code, mainly from office example code. but nothing show in the menu area.

It hard to describe, so put screenshot here. please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Except `St.DrawingArea`, there is no DA in all other inherited libraries. And `St.DrawingArea.get_surface_size()` always 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check the logs... In my case I would do something like `journalctl -f` but your mileage may vary... I would assume that you'll see a lot of something like `JS ERROR: TypeError: cr.move_to is not a function` stuff...

As far as I believe most of your cairo functions are misspelled, the GJS Bindings have CamelCase names...

It's kinda hard to find out and I had no luck finding any documentation on that but after digging into the GJS Code here (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/HEAD/modules/cairo-context.cpp) I was able to understand a lot more on how to do cairo stuff like this (https://www.cairographics.org/manual/) from GJS...